# Name of a children's(?) novel involving a battle in space being affected by the writing of an author on Earth?

Tags: story-identification, novel, childrens-novel

There's two factions battling it out in space, and the "good guys" rock up on Earth to seek the author who is changing their fate with his writing. If I recall correctly, the original author might have even died, leaving their fates unwritten, so some other locals might have to finish the writing for them.

I seem to remember the title being something like Starship Blasters or Starblasters or something like that. I actually thought the novel was one of Nintendo's "Worlds of Power" series, but it doesn't appear to be so.

I read this book in the very late 80s or early 90s, and the title was definitely something "spacey."

Comment: Is there any chance you're mixing a couple of books together? The Author writing the fates bit sounds a lot like Archer's Goon, but it's not spacey (well there's a little bit of spacey stuff). https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47521.Archer_s_Goon?from_search=true

Answer (score 6):

Are you thinking of "Redshirts"? That's a fairly recent novel with the premise that the characters in it are being "written" for a Star Trek knock-off TV show on Earth, and they do end up travelling to Earth to ask them to please write better endings for them.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds pretty interesting, but I don't think so. I read this book in the very late 80s or early 90s, and the title was definitely something "spacey."

Answer (score 3):

Totally thinking "Black Heaven"... but that's an anime series, and the guy was a heavy metal guitarist, not a writer. Pretty similar concept, though. Except heavy metal riffs can power superpowered weapons. Only in Japan.

Comment: Not it, but that sounds pretty awesome! Might have to check it out, given that I don't think I'm ever going to locate this other one.

Comment: @Starzky It has its simularities. Alien race wants this guitarist, who was the headliner for a band known as 'Black Heaven' because his guitar (and riffs) could power their superweapons. Why build a superweapon you can't fire, I have no idea, but it wasn't bad as far as anime goes. At one point he just jams instead of shreds playing more blues than metal and the weapon doesn't fire and the aliens (who of course look human) lose to the evil aliens (who of course look like bugs). Your book sounds awesome, I've read something similar when the hero ran out of world because the writer died!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a little like Terry Pratchett's [Only You Can Save Mankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_You_Can_Save_Mankind). From the Wikipedia article:

> Twelve-year-old Johnny receives a pirate edition of the new video game Only You Can Save Mankind from his friend Wobbler. However, he hasn't been playing for long when the ScreeWee Empire surrenders to him. After accepting the surrender he finds himself inside the game in his dreams, where he must deal with the suspicious Gunnery Officer as well as the understanding Captain, and work out exactly what they're all supposed to do now.
>
> This might all be the result of an over-active imagination except that the ScreeWee have disappeared altogether from everyone else's copy of the game. With the help of another player, Kirsty, who calls herself "Sigourney" (as in Weaver), Johnny must try to get the ScreeWee home.

Fits the time period (1992), and the basic premise, but Johnny Maxwell is a gamer rather than an author.